# Execute different WHERE statement based on IF conditions depending on @variable?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, spring-boot, where-clause

I have a `nativeQuery` in my `DAO` layer inside my Spring Boot app.

Basically, I' passing three parameters, like so:

```
@Query(name = "findInvoicesTour", nativeQuery = true)
    List<InvoiceDto> findInvoices(@Param("invoiceNumber") String invoiceNumber, @Param("companyName") String companyName, @Param("paid") boolean paid);
```

I would like to have different WHERE statements executing depending on value of `companyName`, something like this:

```
if(:companyName = '')
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM invoice_tour it
    WHERE it.paid =: paid AND it.invoice_number LIKE :invoiceNumber
ELSE
    SELECT col1, col2, col3
    FROM invoice_tour it
    WHERE it.paid =: paid AND it.invoice_number LIKE :invoiceNumber AND it.companyName := companyName
```

Or

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
 if(:companyName = '')
        FROM invoice_tour it
        WHERE it.paid =: paid AND it.invoice_number LIKE :invoiceNumber
 ELSE
        FROM invoice_tour it
        WHERE it.paid =: paid AND it.invoice_number LIKE :invoiceNumber AND it.companyName := companyName
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use boolean logic:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM invoice_tour it
WHERE 
    it.paid =: paid 
    AND it.invoice_number LIKE :invoiceNumber
    AND (:companyName = '' OR it.companyName := companyName)
```